# What to do, if esxi host becomes inaccessible?

Tags: vmware-esxi

When i connect with vSphere Client to esxi host, i see an error:

```
An unknown error occured. 
(The request failed because of a connection failure. 
(Unable to connect to remote server)).
```

I can ping server, i even can connect to VMs, located on this server.

But i also can't connect to https client (page with vsphere downloads/etc)

Esxi reboot (i have ability to initiate remote hardware reboot) did not help. What can be done to research/fix this issue?

P.S. I can access other esxi hosts from my machine. Previously i was able to connect from same notebook to this esxi.

P.P.S. Got remote console access. Now i can ssh to this machine, but still can't login via vsphere, in management agent log i see error `SoapAdapter.HTTPService HTTP transaction failed on stream TCP(error:transport endpoint is not connected)`

Comment: Do you have remote console access to the physical machine? Do you have access to log on to esxi via ssh? I'm guessing you don't, but that is where i would start.

Comment: @Andy just got remote console. Updated question text.

Comment: Please provide the versions and build numbers of your ESXi installation.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem last night. My configuration is using the same NAS for both ESXi. So I connected to the secondary ESXi browse the datastore and found the folder of the VMs. Then I located the `.vmx` file, right click on it and press "Add to inventory". So I got my VMs online again and tried to hard restart the ESXi. I wasn't able to connect on it so I was pinging it and after a long time it was online again. If you follow this method make sure that when you power on your VMs to select "I moved this machine"(when vSphere ask you) because if you select "I copied it" you will lose your Windows Licenses.